# LTSP fails while downloading images

Tags: linux, networking, boot, tftp

Some time ago, I've configured LTSP on Debian machine.
I've been using it from time to time and it worked.

Today it stopped working and I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Client says:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 
PXE Software Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation 
Copyright (C) 2010 Oracle Corporation 

CLIENT MAC ADDR: 08 00 27 06 AB AB GUID: 8E607128-4C80-4960-BF72-347FDBDB27B5 
CLIEHT IP: 192.168.1.163 MASK: 255.255.255.0 DHCP IP: 192.168.1.1 
GATEWAY IP: 192.168.1.1
PXE-E35: TFTP read timeout 
PXE-E39: TFTP cannot read from connection 
PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM. 
FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
```

I took a look at server's log, but tftp's logs doesn't seem to be useful:

```
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4568]: RRQ from 192.168.1.163 filename /ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4568]: tftp: client does not accept options
Dec  7 22:44:25 Serwer in.tftpd[4569]: RRQ from 192.168.1.163 filename /ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0
```

(those messages above are generated by tftp with --verbose mode).

So it looks like I've a connection from tftp clients to server, but why did it die?

I could not find any way to see more log informations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site that suggest that it might be a NIC issue:

[pxe_e39_tftp_cannot_read_from_connection](https://www.bootix.com/support/problems_solutions/pxe_e39_tftp_cannot_read_from_connection.html)

SYMPTOM

When being started, the PXE client comes up with the PXE copyright message and completes the DHCP phase, but then displays:

PXE-E39: TFTP cannot read from connection

Depending on the PXE client's system setup boot device list configuration, the PC then either stops or tries to boot from the next boot device in the system setup boot device list.

CAUSE

The "PXE-E39" error indicates that the PXE client encountered a hardware error when trying to send the TFTP acknowledge packet. Note the difference between the "PXE-E39: TFTP cannot read from connection" and the "PXE-E35: TFTP read timeout" error messages. Whereas the "PXE-E35" error signals that the PXE client timed out while waiting for a TFTP reply packet from the TFTP server, the "PXE-E39" error indicates that the PXE client was not able to send the TFTP acknowledge packet in the first place.

RESOLUTION

Check if the network adapter is properly inserted and the network cable properly attached. If this doesn't help, try to replace the network adapter and/or cable. For Lan-On_Board systems, try to insert a separate PXE-enabled network adapter. Also, you might want to update the system BIOS and/or PXE code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it desn't. I was always using ltsp from 3 different machines and all of them stopped working. It would suggest server (hardware) problems, however I have no problems with connections from a console client on a running machine

Comment: Does your pdhcp.ini file have the correct IP address for the tftp server? Perhaps there is a dhcp or ip address change somewhere that is messing up your original config.

Comment: It points to right server. I've used wireshark to verify it, and server receives messages from client. However I'm not very familiar to tftp protocol nor wireshark to make any other conclusions from its reports ;)